# Change text inside an HTML tag with another tag nested

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am talking about a span arranged this way -

```
 <span class="x">
  <span class="y"></span> my text
 </span>
```

Is there a way to change this text without wrapping it inside another tag?

Comment: Is there a text node, or do you want to change the comment?

Comment: @simbabque I wan't to change the text according to an event

Comment: @adeneo I mean for text to show there as written in the title, edited it out since it seems to be confusing you.

Comment: It's confusing because you used a comment, and comments aren't textnodes, but the edit makes it more clear.

Comment: There is also a missing closed `</span>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('y')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = 'some other text';
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c5kWC/3/)

Comment: Could there be a jquery specific solution for this?

Comment: Why would you need a jQuery specific solution when there's an easy way to do it without jQuery? jQuery doesn't really work well with rogue nodes, just with elements, so using the native methods, such as `nextSibling`, is easier.

Comment: I wasn't aware about Jquery's inefficiencies when it comes to text nodes though. Will use your answer, please confirm once that the jquery specific answer I cooked up should be second choice just to be sure.

Comment: @themosquitokiller - The jQuery answer you posted should work fine as well, but the native javascript above should work in all browsers and it's short and concise, so there's no point in using jQuery when you don't have to, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been asked and answered before. 
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156470/jquery-setting-an-elements-text-only-without-removing-other-element-anchor).

The JQuery solution to your question is :

`$('.x').get(0).lastChild.nodeValue = " some-text-2";`.

But anyhow, here's the full answer:

**HTML**

```
<div class='x'>
  <span class='y'></span>
  some-text-1
```

**JS**

```
  $('.x').get(0).lastChild.nodeValue = " some-text-2";
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B7rKs/67/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a comment using jQuery, you will need to use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and look at the [node-type 8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Node.nodeType) for comment.

Comment: And you just removed `<span class="y"></span>`

Comment: yep, this removes the html inside the parent span, not a solution

Comment: Right. Oops. Well. No need to add more stuff. I'll stick with the `contents()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one more **Jquery** based answer apart from the native javascript solution from adeneo.

```
$(".x").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text('blah');
```

Comment: also this $('.x').get(0).lastChild.nodeValue