# Combine usage of .not() and .empty()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable named `MYCELL` which is a `reference to a td` inside a table.

the td looks as follows

```
   <td>
       abc
       <a href="#" class=".myLinkClass">edit</a>
   </td>
```

Right now i wish to `replace` that string `abc` with `def` but keep the link.
I thought i could use the following code:

```
        MYCELL.not(".myLinkClass").empty();
        MYCELL.append("def");
```

But the [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) clears the entire cell. 
Based on this [link](http://api.jquery.com/not/#not-selector) i opted to use a selector inside my `.not()` statement

```
        MYCELL.not(MYCELL.find(".myLinkClass")).empty();
```

Any idea on how to `empty (including other html-tags)` everything in my td without removing any links (`<a href>`) or any elements with the class `.myLinkClass` ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156470/jquery-setting-an-elements-text-only-without-removing-other-element-anchor

Comment: @SSA not quite. In the solution offered the textvalue is always the last child. In my case my `td`can contain many things (including other html-tags\elements) which would have to be removed aswell. The problem isn't limited to simply replacing the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to ensure you can select text nodes as well:

```
MYCELL.contents().filter(function() {
    return !$(this).is("a"); // Only select nodes where are not <a> tags
}).remove(); // Use .remove instead
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5bp540n/)