# How to change only text inside a div which has other divs

Tags: jquery, html

I have html below. What I want to do depends on some conditions. I want to keep changing the text which is `Sometitle`.

```
<div id="header">
    Sometitle
    <div>
        <div>
            aa
        </div>
        <div>
            bb
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using Jquery below but it removes the other divs also.

```
$("#header").text("Its a thrusday today !");
```

How do I get this done? I cannot modify this HTML in any case. I just have to use jquery and get this thing done.

Here is a jsfiddle I created : http://jsfiddle.net/qYUBp/

Comment: You control the JavaScript, but have no influence over the HTML?

Comment: its not my project, I am just working on it for a day'

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/in-jquery-how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements

Comment: @Yasser : doesn't *working on it* means you have the control over the HTML?

Comment: no @andri actually this HTML is rendered by jqgrid, I just wanted a quick fix for this and thanks to [aruncc](http://stackoverflow.com/users/432216/arjuncc) I got it. Thank you guys !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont want it in a single line.

```
var tmp=$("#header>div").html();
$("#header").text("its thursday").append('<div>'+tmp+'</div>');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/qYUBp/6/)

Answer (score 3):

That text `Sometitle` is an orphan node, you are going to want to wrap an element around it to properly manipulate it

```
<div id="header">
    <span>Sometitle</span>
    <div>
        <div>
            aa
        </div>
        <div>
            bb
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

But since you regrettably cannot change the html, you could do as the solution suggests in the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/in-jquery-how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements#4106910). They had a typo that I corrected here:

```
var your_div = document.getElementById('header');
var text_to_change = your_div.childNodes[0];
text_to_change.nodeValue = 'new text';
```

check your [updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYUBp/5/)

Comment: He says he can't alter the HTML.

Comment: I'd agree, but the OP specifically stated they need to do this without changing the HTML.

Comment: i guess you used this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/in-jquery-how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements#4106910

Comment: Yes @SachinRawal, as I stated in my explanation, I did. But I will update with a link for further clarification. There is a typo in that answer that prevented it from working, so I corrected it here, I also submitted an edit to that answer

Comment: yeahh i knw . i checked it..thnx anywys as i am also trying but not able to make it properly thnx buddy

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#header").html($("#header").html().replace("Sometitle","Its a thrusday today !"));
```

Comment: the title needs to be updated again n again, so the replace("old", "new") cannot work in my case

Comment: This has the downside of removing all event handlers et al. Still a nice idea.

Comment: This can be done easily by add a span to the title but yasser want to do without changing the html . So this is the way i found.

Answer (score 0):

for this case only, when rendering to browser

```
var new_s = "Its a thrusday today !";
var s = $("#header").children(":first").html();
$("#header").text(new_s+"<div>"+s+"</div>");
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea that the text "`<div>`" and "`</div>`" appears in the document. Did you mean `.html(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

can you check this

```
headerClone = $("#header").clone();
$(headerClone).find('div').remove();
var currentText = $(headerClone).html().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t)/gm,"");

newHtml = $("#header").html().replace(currentText,"Gotcha");
$("#header").html(newHtml);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PCXNv/)