# How to safetly replace the value after the "td" tag? (In JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside the "td" tag, how do I replace the "BMW" word after the "span" tag without removing the whole "span" tag script?  (In JQuery).

The word "BMW" is wildcard wording.  It can be "Ford", "Volvo", etc.

I'm using *JQuery* version 2.0

```
$('#'....).???

<td>
   <span column="17" style="cursor:pointer"></span> BMW
</td>
```

Comment: See this question and answer for your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4106809/870729

Comment: have you successfully targeted that element? Without the surrounding html we may not be able to help you get to it. Once targeted, you can easily use regex to remove anything not within the first span tag

Comment: [Do not ever use regex on html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/209259).

Comment: Yea, I had successfully target the "TD" element as "$('#'+jqgridSpreadsheetId+'ghead_'+jqGridGroup[x].idx.toString()+'_'+x.toString())" which gives me the whole values inside the "TD" element.

Comment: [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use nextSibling if the text node is the next sibling like in the question:

```
$('span[column="17"]').get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue = 'Volvo';
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yNnKD/)

Comment: Would that work if the make was Alpha Romeo? next node would be text node, but is alpha romeo 2 text nodes?

Comment: @KaiQing - yup, that works just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/yNnKD/1/

Comment: What's get() doing here?

Comment: @isherwood - it converts the jQuery selection to a native DOM element.

Comment: @isherwood returns DOM element that matches the selector

Comment: Ah, because nodeValue isn't jQuery. Cool.

Comment: Does "get()" works in JQuery v2.0?

Comment: @fletchsod - works everywhere ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this out... Note that I'm omitting any text nodes that are whitespace:

```
$("YOUR TD SELECTOR HERE")
    .contents()
    .filter(
        function() { 
            return this.nodeType == 3 && $(this).text().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, ''); 
        }
    )
    .text('text to replace here');
```

Comment: +1 for filtering whitespace.  Depending on how the html is written and/or minified, this definitely needs to be accounted for. But .text doesn't seem to work (replaceWith does)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/), [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), and [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

EXAMPLE:

```
$('table').find('td')
          .contents()
          .filter(function() {
              return this.nodeType === 3;
           })
           .replaceWith("hello world");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V4wF5/1/

Comment: This breaks if the HTML is written with multiple line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I forgot the closing end parenthesis for the first call.

Not sure how you are identifying the column so you may need to change the selector.  This is a straight search and replace.  You did want to only replace the word BMW, correct?

```
// Example: $(table.cars td)
$('td').each(function()
{
    var repl = $(this).html().replace('BMW', 'Ford');
    $(this).html(repl);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any nice jQuery solution, so I provide low level javaScript way. Sorry for that, but believe it helps.

```
$("td").each(function(i,v){
  for (var i = 0;i < v.childNodes.length;i++){
    if (v.childNodes[i].constructor.name=="Text"){
      v.childNodes[i].nodeValue=v.childNodes[i].nodeValue.replace(/BMW/,"Volvo");
    }
  }        
});
```

*Edit:*
It's little bin incompatible so it's better version:

```
$("td").each(function(i,v){
  for (var i = 0;i < v.childNodes.length;i++){
    if (v.childNodes[i] instanceof Text){
      v.childNodes[i].nodeValue=v.childNodes[i].nodeValue.replace(/BMW/,"Volvo");
    }
  }        
});
```

Here I bring it to life: http://jsbin.com/ItotOPo/1/edit?html,js,output