# Truncate text without hitting nested link

Tags: javascript, jquery, truncate

I have paragraph that has a read more link nested in it.

```
<p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah <a href="link">Read More</a></p>
```

I need to truncate the paragraph text and end it with an ellipsis without affecting anything in the `<a></a>` tag.

I can do the truncation of the text using `$(p).text($(p).text().substring(0,n)+'...');` but of course if I grab the paragraph using `$(p).text()` it would include the link and would lop it off.

Is there a way to grab, and then replace with the truncated version, the text of the `<p>` without affecting the `</a>`. Preferably without having to use any regex or having to clone the link and re-append it?

Comment: you want to do this by clicking on anchor tag ?
or on page load ?

Comment: @SunilKumar This would happen on page load

Comment: Take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements

Comment: `Preferably without having to use any regex `  why so?

Comment: @MehranTorki interesting hadn't thought to use ChildNodes, will look into that (if this is a duplicate to that feel free to mark it I'm not sure).

Comment: @Reddy Personal preference really I view RegEx as messy especially for something that (I thought) would be so trivial.

Comment: @DasBeasto Much easier way to the job ! I'll flag it.

Comment: @DasBeasto got you..

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this using [**`nodeType`**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp). Then you can change value using [**`textContent`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property.

> For a text node, the nodeType property will return 3.

```js
alert($('p').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
})[0].textContent);

//set new value
$('p').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
})[0].textContent = 'New text ';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah <a href="link">Read More</a></p>
```

Comment: looks good!! do you mind explaining what `this.nodeType == 3;` does?

Comment: @Reddy I just did.

Comment: Please check whether the question is duplicate or not. If not, then try to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  
  var x = $("p").contents().get(0).nodeValue; // This will grab the text ignoring the other nodes:

  $("p").html(x.substring(0, 5) + '...' + $("p").find("a").wrap("<p>").parent().html()); // Setting x and appending the <a> html

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah <a href="link">Read More</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try following script:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var hrefTag = $('a').attr('href');   
        $('p').html('<a href="' + hrefTag + '">Read More</a>');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah <a href="link">Read More</a></p>
```