# Update text of HTMLElement without affecting child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use `JavaScript`/`JQuery` to modify the text of an HTMLElement without affecting the child HTMLElements.

I have html that looks like:

```
<span class="js-my-parent-span">
    "Hello, World!"
    <span class="js-my-child-span">
    </span>
</span>
```

I have attemted to change the `Hello, World!` text using the `innerHTML` and `innerText` attributes as well as the `html()` method from `JQuery`. All of these methods also `overwrite` the child span.

I just want to update the text.

Comment: Then update the text node and stop trying to change the content of the whole span.

Comment: `theEl.contents().get(0).textContent = 'foo'`. or even better, `theEl[0].childNodes[0].textContent = 'foo'`

Comment: You can mark one of answer to finishing this discussion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change an element's text without changing its child elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the text in its own container, which is probably the best pattern here.

```js
$('.text-content').text('Something else')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="js-my-parent-span">
    <span class="text-content">Hello, World!</span>
    <span class="js-my-child-span">Other content</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Good point, I feel like an idiot. This looks like a reasonable solution, I'll accept the answer if no one comes along with a more precise solution that doesn't involve modifying the html.

Comment: There are *ways* to do it, but I wouldn't suggest them as a solid pattern long term

Comment: After reviewing the answers this really is the most appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can get childs of `span` using [**`childNodes`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) property. `childNodes[0]` contain `"Hello, World!"` text.

```js
$(".parent")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = "New hello world-";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="parent">
    "Hello, World!"
    <span>Child text</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target the first child node of the element, which is specifically the text node holding the content. However, if the span is mid-sentence, this will not work.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById('test').childNodes[0].textContent = "It worked without changing "
}
```

```html
<span id="test">Change this text without removing <span>what's in the span</span></span>
<button>Do It</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var childs = $(".js-my-parent-span").find(".js-my-child-span");

$(".js-my-parent-span").html('"Hello, world i have successfully changed only the text and not the child element!" ').append(childs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="js-my-parent-span">
    "Hello, World!"
    <span class="js-my-child-span">This is child span
    </span>
</span>
```