# Change .text() content and keep child html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you tell me how to remove character `@` from this span tag without changing all child html(s)?

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  // ...
});
```

```css
#name {
  background-color: #ccc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <span id="name">
    <a href="#">Harry</a>
  </span> 
  
  says: Hello @<span id="name">
    <a href="#">Hermione</a>
  </span>
</span><br />

<button>Remove</button>
```

My idea: get the parent `.text()`, split character `@`, override parent text (`parent.text('')`) and append 2 parts to the parent. But this way has a big problem: all child html(s) wouldn't be kept.

Comment: Aside :: You can't have duplicated ID's ... ID must be unique

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added an id to the outer `<span>` and deduplicated your name ids.

```js
$('button').click(function () {

  $('#outer').html($('#outer').html().replace(/@/,''));
  
});
```

```css
#name {
  background-color: #ccc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='outer'><span id="name"><a href="#">Harry</a></span> says: Hello @<span id="name2"><a href="#">Hermione</a></span></span>

<br />

<button>Remove</button>
```

Comment: The answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements are probably better

Comment: I'm sorry, can I expand my question? Example: If in the span tag, I have more than 1 character `@`, and I only want to remove one of them (previous the user name). How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe edit the question to show the expanded example. And also explain how you would tell the difference between an @ before a user name and another @. There's probably a regex for it, if you can actually describe the difference clearly.

Comment: I forget that I can use regex to detect `@` + `username` and `@` + (not) + `username`. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you should change the duplicate `id` attributes to classes, or remove them entirely.

To solve your actual issue you can loop through the nodes held within the top level `span` and remove any `@` characters which appear in any textNode values. Try this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('body > span').contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
      this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace('@', '');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#name {
  background-color: #ccc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <span class="name">
    <a href="#">Harry</a>
  </span> says: Hello @<span class="name">
    <a href="#">Hermione</a>
  </span>
</span>
<br />

<button>Remove</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! A small question: how do I know the `this.nodeType` is 3?

Comment: Here you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType You could replace `3` with `Node.TEXT_NODE`, however it may not be supported in older browsers.

Comment: ... Im looking for something like `var nodeType  = ...; if (this.nodeType == nodeType) {}`. Thanks for the link