# Changing text of div without changing its inner tag contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hQpNQc0yWjthkYhGT3vV?p=preview) I have a `div` that contains some text and a `span`, also with text.

My objective is to change the text of the `div`, without changing the text of the `span`.

I tried with jQuery but the problem is that the entire `div` text changes, replacing also the `span` text, any ideas?

HTML

```
<div id="id1">some text to change <span>THIS TEXT STAYS</span></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var id1 = $("#id1");
    id1.text("New Text");
});
```

Comment: `id1.firstChild.textContent = 'some text changed'`

Comment: For your use, do you have to worry about the `<span>` being in the beginning or middle of the text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change an element's text without changing its child elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is one of the rare places jQuery doesn't do much for you. You want to go straight to the `Text` node in that `div`:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var id1 = $("#id1");
    // The [0] accesses the raw HTMLDivElement inside the jQuery object
    // (this isn't accessing internals, it's documented).
    // The `firstChild` is the first node within the `div`, which is
    // the text node you want to change. `nodeValue` is the text of the
    // Text node.
    id1[0].firstChild.nodeValue = "New Text";
});
```

```html
<div id="id1">some text to change <span>THIS TEXT STAYS</span></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or without using jQuery (other than `ready`) at all:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var id1 = document.getElementById("id1");
    id1.firstChild.nodeValue = "New Text";
});
```

```html
<div id="id1">some text to change <span>THIS TEXT STAYS</span></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 10):

Please have a look at this approach:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
  $("#id1").contents().get(0).nodeValue = "New Text 1 "
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1">some text to change <span>THIS TEXT STAYS</span></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code,

```js
var id = document.getElementById('id1');
var newText = id.childNodes[0];
newText.nodeValue = 'Replaced by me ';
```

```html
<div id="id1">some text to change <span>THIS TEXT STAYS</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `outerHTML` :

```js
   $('#id1').html("New Text "+$('#id1 span')[0].outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1">some text to change <span>THIS TEXT STAYS</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already accepted an answer but I figured for the sake of diversity I could show you a jQuery solution:

**html**

```
<div id="id1">
    some text to change <span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>THIS TEXT STAYS</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery 1.12.4**

```
var $id1 = $('#id1');
var $span = $id1.find('span');
$id1.text('New Text'); // or $id1.html('New Text'); // your choice
$id1.append($span);
```

---

This is probably not the most efficient solution but it gets the job done.

Answer (score -1):

Html:-

```
 <div id="id1">some text to change <span>THIS TEXT STAYS</span></div>
```

Jquery:-

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var abcd = $('span').text();
    $("#id1").html("New Text "+'<span>'+abcd+'</span>');
});
```

We can reconstruct the entire required DOM by getting the span tage **text()**

Please check the Updated 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jb669r8p/2/)

Comment: It doesn't preserve the span element, it wipes it and only keeps the value. If the div is updated again, the text that was previously in the span won't be there at all any more.

Comment: Please check the Update code now i am getting the text of span tag and regenerating the span tag so now is it working or not please siuggest