# How to Change the Html of an Element before a Child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I had the following div:

```
<div id = "master">
     "Random Text
     <span id = "unknown">...</span>
</div>
```

If I didn't know the id of the span, how would I modify the `"Random Text"` using jQuery?

Note the [proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements)'s answer is javascript not jQuery.

Comment: @JorgeMejia you aren't reading the question. OP wants to change the text node

Comment: Do you have any means by which you can identify the text that you wish to change? Will it always appear before a `<span>` tag, will it always be the string `"Random Text"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the node type property to find the text node

node type 3 is for the text node.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp

You can use the nodeValue property to set the text of a text node element

```js
var textNodeList = $("#master")
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
  });


textNodeList[0].nodeValue = "Not Random Text";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "master">
     "Random Text
     <span id = "unknown">...</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not have it's own text node methods.

Abstract approach using only jQuery that doesn't require knowing or using native dom methods or properties

```
$('#master').html(function(){
   return $(this).children().clone(true);// only return elements, clone to preserve any possible event handlers
}).prepend('Some new text');
```

Assumes there is only one text node child of `#master`

Answer (score -1):

You could do this:

```
var masterDiv = $('#master');
var text_to_change = masterDiv.childNodes[0];
text_to_change.nodeValue = 'new text';
```

This should get is working.

Comment: Whats the difference. just change the selectors

Comment: @Mahi jQuery doesn't have text node methods. Stop complaining about using native dom methods if you don't have a solution yourself

Comment: that's why he asked question to solve using jquery only

Comment: @Mahi what OP asked is irrelevant if such methods don't exist.

Comment: but you can make using pure jquery .

Comment: @Mahi then provide a solution instead of complaining about all the others. No matter what you do you need to use native dom methods or properties. There are numerous ways to do this

Comment: i don't post answer just for votes. i have already flag as duplicate . and OP Didn't asked to solve this question using JS. read question before posting answer.

Comment: @Mahi but that solution also requires using native dom properties that are not jQuery. The jQuery library is javascript. Stop all the complaining!! That being said, I posted an answer that does meet your criteria

Comment: @Mahi I too don't understand what's your deal? You either use jquery or javascript, it is not going to make any difference.

Comment: i know we can simply do using js. but he meant can we do using jquery . and you are posting js answer that means you can't do with jquery ?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this?

```
$('#unknown')[0].previousSibling.nodeValue = 'something else';
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/862mau02/4/)