# Addclass after desired element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to do addClass in jQuery,

When i do try below codes, it result me like image 1

```
 $('#contineButton').html('Continue').addClass('fa fa-chevron-right');
 $('#contineButton').html('Continue').after().addClass('fa fa-chevron-right');
```

[image]

but, iwant to get the result like below image 2

[image]

Original button code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success next-step" id="contineButton">
                ${vo.continueButtonText} <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: What does your HTML and CSS look like? Either way, `after()` is not what you need as that's designed to insert content after the selected element

Comment: Is the *Original button code* the output of your `addClass` operation or what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You just replaced your _whole_ button content with the text `Continue` - so the `i` element does not even exist any more.

Comment: You probably want `$('#contineButton').html('Continue <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using after() and you should be using append()

```
 $('#contineButton').html('Continue').append('<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
```

EXPLANATION:

You used html->addClass wich in the first try will add the class to the current object (the button) and in the second try (with after) will attempt to do it in an empty element inserted afterwards.
The `html` replaced the content of the button completly so the `<i>` didn't existed anymore.

Comment: Why not go `$('#contineButton').html('Continue <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');`directly in that case?

Comment: @connexo just for the sake of keeping both things separated.

Comment: What benefits does that offer to compensate for the disadvantages?

Comment: Readability, change to prepend is independant of the order it was typed. If you want to avoid the disadvantages of 2 jquery calls you can also type it straight into the html.

Comment: If you intention is to separate stuff, why not go `$('<i></i>').appendTo($('#contineButton').html('Continue')).addClass("fa fa-chevron-right");`?

Comment: `$('<i></i>')`? There is no <i> tag to select

Comment: `$('<i></i>')` creates an `i` element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
document.getElementById('contineButton').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
```

But it can be achieved with CSS.

Comment: Thanks. It may be out of this topic, but I don't understand why are people trying to achieve these trivial tasks with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

To add text before tag you need to use `.before` jquery function:

```
$('#contineButton i').before('Continue');
```

For your case you need replace text with new text string:

```
$('#contineButton').contents()[0].remove();
$('#contineButton i').before('Continue');
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This only works incase you're using
[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Is there a reason why you are trying to achieve this using jQuery?

Should work with this html/css code.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
  Button <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Did I miss that OP mentioned they are using Bootstrap?

Comment: @connexo the fact that he is using 'btn btn-success' looks like he is yeah.

Comment: I've been using the same naming syntax for my button css classes even before Bootstrap existed. So yes, it may be a hint, and no, answers should not suggest using Bootstrap because it is definitely not clear.

Comment: Their screenshots also suggest it.

Comment: *suggests*  - yes. *states* - no.

Comment: Yes you're right, I was 99% sure he was using bootstrap.
I'm just here trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success next-step" id="contineButton">${vo.continueButtonText} <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
</button>



$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#contineButton').contents().filter(function() {
                console.log(this)
            return this.nodeType == 3;
        })[0].nodeValue = "The text you want to replace with"
});
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ewqva3fw/)

Comment: more info can be found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements