# How do I change the text of the first tag in nested tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the text in the following h5 tag:

```
<h5 id="status"><img id="status-icon" src="some image">Change Text</h5>
```

I am using:

```
var heading = document.getElementById("status")
heading.textContent = "Resolved"
```

The above replaces the img tag.

How can I change only the h5's text ?

Comment: if you don't want the image to ever be replaced there, `heading.textContent = "<img id="status-icon" src="#">Resolved"`

Comment: @Shinratensei The image in the actual code will be some existing and different image each time, so I am not sure how I can do what you mention.

Comment: hmmm, do those images follow a certain order or logic?

Comment: It's more like, a green flag if the status is resolved and a red if not.

Comment: then I guess you have to check something else before modifying the heading. How are you going to do it?

Comment: @GiannisIordanou you can use `childNodes` property as in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `childNodes` property to get the second node which is actually the text. so the image remains the same.

```js
var elm = document.getElementById("status");
elm.childNodes[1].nodeValue = "Resolved";
```

```html
<h5 id="status"><img id="status-icon" src="#" alt="image is unchanged"> Change Text</h5>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `.textContent` of `.firstElementChild.nextSibling` of `heading`

```js
var heading = document.getElementById("status");
heading.firstElementChild.nextSibling.textContent = "Resolved";
```

```html
<h5 id="status"><img id="status-icon" src="#" alt="status-icon">Change Text</h5>
```

or use `.querySelector()` and `.nextSibling`

```js
var heading = document.getElementById("status");
heading.querySelector("img").nextSibling.textContent = "Resolved";
```

```html
<h5 id="status"><img id="status-icon" src="#" alt="status-icon">Change Text</h5>
```

Comment: Which element is heading.firstElementChild.nextSibling ?

Comment: @GiannisIordanou The `.nextSibling` of `heading` element `.firstElementChild` `<img>` element is a `#text` node, not an HTML element

Comment: @guest271314 i think using `childNodes` is more simple

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same using below JavaScript code :

```
document.getElementById("status").lastChild.textContent = "Resolved";
```

**Demo:**

```js
document.getElementById("status").lastChild.textContent = "Resolved";
```

```html
<h5 id="status"><img width="100" height="100" id="status-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/kP1Gj7J.jpg"/>Change Text</h5>
```

Comment: Actually, this is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```js
var heading = document.getElementById("status");
heading.childNodes[1].nodeValue = "Resolved";
```

```html
<h5 id="status"><img id="status-icon" src="some image"\>Change Text</h5>
```

Comment: How is present Answer different from this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46275215/? What is purpose of "\" character at `<img>` tag?

Comment: what's the point of posting the solution which is already posted?

Comment: @Niladri haven't seen another answer similar to mine.
By the way this solution was already clear from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements)

Comment: @guest271314 regarding the "/" it's the proper way to end the <img/> tag. In this way is complaint also to XHTML.

Comment: _"regarding the "/" it's the proper way to end the <img/> tag. In this way is complaint also to XHTML."_  `<img>` tag is self-closing. "/" character does not appear at Answer at close of `<img>` tag.

Comment: It's self-closing but not well formatted.
If you want a well XML formatted document you have to close every tag.