# change text of an element without changing child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('button').click(function(){ $(this).prev('label').append('<b>ed</b>').text('Press');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Click<b>ed</b></label>
<button>Here</button>
```

I want to keep the element `<b></b>` or any element exisiting changing the `.text()`

The steps i'm trying to handle is the following

`.append('<b>ed</b>')` at first i appended the new element `<b>`;

Driectly after appending the new element i changed the text to **`Press`** `.text('Press');`

What i'm trying to do is copying the added `<b>ed</b>` element before changing the text `.text('Press');` then add it again after changing the `text()`

So it would be like

```
var element = $(this).prev('label').clone('b');
$(this).prev('label').append('<b>ed</b>').text('Press'+element+'');
```

The problem i keep getting the element value = `[Object object]`

Comment: `$(this).prev('label').html('Pressed<b>ed</b>');` should work for you.

Comment: @Daerik I know, But i want to understand how to handle it if i used `.append()` then went to `.text() or .html()` for special cases

Comment: Why not just use a variable?  `var lbl=$(this).prev("label");  lbl.append("<b>ed</b>");  lbl.text("press");`   (note this will not give you what you want as it will overwrite "press", but that's what your code is trying to do.

Comment: @freedomn-m It is like that, But i'm trying to copy the appended element instead of the label itself.

Comment: Can you clarify this in the question title and provide html for before / expected after?   It's not clear what you mean by "want to *keep*"

Comment: @freedomn-m i `appened <b>` element, Then i change the entire `parent` element `text` which contains the `appended <b>`, But i want to prevent the `text` from removing the `appended <b>`, My solution was  trying to copy it and readd it again, Instead of appending it again. but didn't work. Since i couldn't copy the element using `children('b') nor clone('b')`

Comment: @freedomn-m updated the question a little

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access the text part, you need to use `.contents()`

See [this answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4106957/2181514) for more info.

```js
$("#x").append("<b> pressed</b>")
       .contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType == 3;}).first()
       .replaceWith("well done");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='x'>Press</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `.html()` method in order to display the text desired as **HTML**.

```js
$('button').click(function(){ $(this).prev('label').html('Press<b>ed</b>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Click<b>ed</b></label>
<button>Here</button>
```

Another solution:

```
$('button').click(function(){ $(this).prev('label').empty().append('<b>ed</b>').html('Press'+$(this).prev('label').html());
})
```

Comment: The problem is that i want to do it using `appened()` then `text() or html()` Something for a Dynamic usage.

Comment: @AXAI, try second solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/). Keep in mind that `.text()` will replace the element's content in its entirety, so it's important to use `.append()` last.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var boldedElem = $(this).prev('label').find('b');
    $(this).prev('label').text('Press').append(boldedElem);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Click<b>ed</b></label>
<button>Here</button>
```

Comment: Yes, the part of `.append($('<b>ed</b>'))`, I want to copy it from the label itself instead of creating it. i appened element `<b>ed</b>`, Then change the entire .text while keeping it exisiting.

Comment: `<b>ed</b>` in the html doesn't exist untill i appened it `$(this).prev('label').append(<b>ed</b>)` then i change the using `.text('Press')`, So i don't think `find` would work, I'm trying to do something like copying the <b> after appending it, then adding it again after `.text()`

Answer (score 1):

Look for all `<b>` in this label, take the last one and modify its content using `html()`

```js
$('button').click(function(){ 
var label = $(this).prev('label');
label.find('b').last().html('Press');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Click<b>ed</b></label>
<button>Here</button>
```

Comment: Script does not replace the text, but appends the string to the end of `<b/>`.

Comment: i thought this was what was expected. i'll edit. Please comment before downvoting -_-

Comment: TBH it's still unclear to me what the OP actually wants.

Comment: @BoffinbraiN agreed, so we should be finding out, not wildly guessing

Comment: right, sorry i forgot to format :-) thanks for your edit

Comment: i thought i understood what was asked, but considering the number of different answers i guess everyone understood it differently -_-