# Get element by attribute in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get an element using attribute. I want to change the text that says "Card security code" to "CVV". There are many label elements so I can't get element by the tag name.

```
<label for="cvv">Card security code <span class="required">*</span></label>
```

Comment: use ID it is more unique.

Comment: $("label [for='cvv']").text("CVV"); Try this.

Comment: besides tag name, you can use `id`, `class`or almost every css selector (with jquery) to look after a  html element

Comment: I didn't had access to the html and there was no class or id with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change an element's text without changing its child elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [attribute value selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get the , then use descendant selector to get `span`'s afterwards its [previousSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) property to target the text node to change its [nodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue).

```js
$('label[for="cvv"] span')[0].previousSibling.nodeValue = 'CVV'
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="cvv">Card security code <span class="required">*</span></label>
```

Comment: For those wondering what the `[0]` does, since every jQuery object also masquerades as an array, you can use the dereferencing operator `[0]` to get at the underlying JavaScript node to easily use `previousSibling`. `.get(0)` would also have worked.