# Add class to labels forms in jquery

Tags: jquery, label, hide

I'm trying to edit the wordpress contact form to customize it. 
I have already add function to use placeholder for my labels. 
So now I wish add a class whish correspond to their "for=" attribute for each of them in order to hide the label's text.

There is a way to do that in jquery ?

this is my jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#user_login').attr('placeholder', 'Name');
    jQuery('#user_email').attr('placeholder', 'Email');
    jQuery('#user_pass').attr('placeholder', 'Password');         

});
```

and my html:

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="http://localhost/patrick/waf" method="post" style="position: static; left: 0px;">
    <p>
        <label for="user_login">Nom d’utilisateur ou adresse e-mail<br>
        <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" aria-describedby="login_error" class="input" value="" size="20" placeholder="Name"></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="user_pass">Mot de passe<br>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" aria-describedby="login_error" class="input" value="" size="20" placeholder="Password"></label>
    </p>
        <div>
        <div id="areyouhuman">
            <label>
                <span class="checkme" role="checkbox" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false"></span>
                <i class="checkme">Oui, je suis un humain.</i>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div id="msg" class="hidden">Session expirée, merci de réessayer.</div>
        <input type="hidden" name="captcha_key" id="captcha_key" value="">
    </div>
        <p class="forgetmenot"><label for="rememberme"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" checked="checked"> Se souvenir de moi</label></p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Se connecter">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://localhost/patrick/wp-admin/">
        <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1">
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an attribute selector.

```
$("label[for=user_login],label[for=user_email],label[for=user_pass]")
    .contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 3; }).first().replaceWith("");
```

See [How can I change an element's text without changing its child elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements/4106957#4106957) for an explanation of how that works. This complicated code is necessary because the `<label>` elements wrap around the inputs, so you can't just do `.text("")` because that would also remove the inputs.

You could also just get rid of the labels entirely with `unwrap()`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#user_login').attr('placeholder', 'Name').unwrap();
    jQuery('#user_email').attr('placeholder', 'Email').unwrap();
    jQuery('#user_pass').attr('placeholder', 'Password').unwrap();         

});
```

Comment: thank you :)
the unwrap working fine, but not the replacewith, My text still there

Comment: Take a look at the question I linked to, maybe one of the other solutions works.