# How do you remove text without affecting child elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

I have a div with child divs and also some text. Using jQuery/JS I want to leave the child divs alone and remove the text.

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>keep this</div>
  <div>keep this</div>
  Some random text that can't be predicted (to be removed)
  <div>keep this</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As stated in a comment below, I don't have the ability to modify the DOM.  I can only inject JS.

Comment: Possible duplicated from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whit `Javascript` you can just get all the [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) of the element with `id=parent` and then traverse these childs to [.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) those that have [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) equal to [Node.TEXT_NODE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType#Node_type_constants):

```js
let childs = document.getElementById("parent").childNodes;
childs.forEach(c => c.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && c.remove());
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>keep this</div>
  <div>keep this</div>
  Some random text that can't be predicted (to be removed)
  <div>keep this</div>
</div>
```

Or alternatively and using [JQuery.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) you can use next approach:

```js
$("#parent").contents().each(function()
{
    if (this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) this.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
  <div>keep this</div>
  <div>keep this</div>
  Some random text that can't be predicted (to be removed)
  <div>keep this</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also use `c.nodeType == 3` (first example) or `this.nodeType == 3` (second example). :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) to find all text nodes which are a direct child of your root element and remove them.

```js
function removeChildTextNodes(root)
{
  var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL, {
    acceptNode: function(node) { if(node.nodeType === 3) return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT },
  }, true);
  var currentNode = treeWalker.firstChild();
  while(currentNode)
  {
      var removedNode = treeWalker.currentNode;
      currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode()
      removedNode.remove();
  }
}

var root = document.querySelector('#parent');
removeChildTextNodes(root);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <img />
  Some random text that can't be predicted (to be removed)
  <div>keep this</div>
  Some random text that can't be predicted (to be removed)
  <h2>
    keep this
  </h2>
  Some <strong>random</strong> text that can't be predicted (to be removed)
  <a>keep this</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using jQuery

```js
$('.parent')
  // Return direct descendants. This also returns text nodes, as opposed to children()
  .contents()
  // Target text nodes only
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
  }).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div>keep this</div>
  <div>keep this</div>
  Some random text that can't be predicted (to be removed)
  <div>keep this</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  Some random text in another location
  <div>keep this</div>
  <div>keep this</div>
  <div>keep this</div>
  More random text
</div>
```