# Replacing text within a label

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML which looks like:

[image]

I want to replace the word `Search:` with another word `some word`. How can I do this? I tried:

```
document.querySelector("#state-covid-data_filter label").innerText = "some word"
```

but this also replaces the `input` tag.

I also tried:

```
document.querySelector("#state-covid-data_filter label").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#state-covid-data_filter label").innerHTML.replace("Search:","Some word:")
```

But then the `input` tag loses the events registered. How could I just replace the `text` such that everything else remains fine.

Comment: Wrap it in a `<span>`. (If you cannot change the HTML, get the textNode child and change that)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change an element's text without changing its child elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text node by `childNodes`.

If the text is always at the beginning of the element, you can just change it like this:

```js
document.querySelector('label').childNodes[0].textContent = 'Some word:';
```

```html
<label>
  Search:
  <input type="text" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to redraw the label, it would account for the scenarios when your `label` may not have any text content to begin with, or when it's placed after the `input`

```
const label = document.querySelector("label");
const input = label.querySelector("input");
label.innerHTML = "NEW STRING";
label.append(input);
```

Answer (score -2):

Because your `input` is inside your `label` it is also part of the `innerText` you can add a element around the text and select that instead like this

```js
document.querySelector("#your_id label span").innerText = "some word";
```

```html
<div id="your_id">
  <label for="">
    <span>Your text</span>
    <input type="search">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You could, but you don't have to