# Why can't I set the innerHTML of my span tag in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to print the response received from my AJAX call to my PHP script. This is my code:

**JavaScript:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index_backend.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { "input": "id"},
    success: function(response) {

            let str="";
            const arr=response.split(" ");
            for(var i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++){
                str=str.concat(" ",arr[i]);
            }

            //console.log(arr); shows correct output
            //console.log(arr[arr.length-1]); shows correct output

            document.getElementById("qid").style.display="block";
            $("#qid").text(str); //works
            $("#qrtr_id").html(arr[arr.length-1]); //doesn't work
           
                            
    },
    complete: function() {

    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<span id="qid" style="display: none;">
    Some random text here :&nbsp;
    <span id="qrtr_id" style="color: crimson;"></span>
</span>
```

---

All I am trying to do, is split the `response` and print a part of the `response` (excluding the last word) in a separate `<span>` and the last word in a separate `<span>`. But the last word never gets printed, although when I `console.log()` the word, then it shows correctly.

I've re-checked my `<span>` ids and they are correct too. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change an element's text without changing its child elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements)

Comment: I've reformatted your code to make the html nesting more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#qid").text(str);` rewrites the content of `qid` with the text you pass it.

The content of `qid` includes the span with the `qrtr_id` so when you rewrite it you destroy that span.

`$("#qrtr_id")` then doesn't find any element.

Wrap `Some random text here :&nbsp;` in another span and target that instead of `qid`.

Comment: I want my `qid` and my `qrtr_id` to be in the same line and have different text colors. Hence my html code is like that, one inside the other.

Comment: @Lubji — Well, that won't work, so do what I said instead.

Comment: To be explicit: `<span id="qid"><span>your text<span><span id=qrtr_id></span></span>` then `$("#qid>span:first").text(str)` - will still show them "in the same line"

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not mix jquery and vanilla javascript, please :).

Second, the main problem is that you are using the .text(text) method. This will replace all content inside the target element, so your second span will not exist anymore. This will replace the innerHTML with the text.

So my suggestion is to use the append method to add your last span inside the first one.

```
// the main span
const $firstSpan = $('#id');

// add the whole text, except the last word into the main span
const $firstSpan.text(arr.slice(0, arr.length-1).join(' '));

// create a span do wrapp the last word
const $lastWord = $('<span>');

// add the last word into the correspondent span
$lastWord.text(arr[arr.length-1]);

// add the last word span into the main span
$($lastWord).appendTo($firstSpan);
```

Comment: Sorry, I have sent before I finish writing the code.

Comment: You only need to recreate the last span. Or you can make the last span a sibling of the first one, instead of a child.

Comment: `$lastWord` is already a jQuery object; there's no need to wrap it in `$(...)`.

Answer (score -3):

As I can see, use <= in for loop as below.

```
for(var i=0; I <= arr.length-1; i++)
```

OR, use <arr.length in for loop as below.

```
for(var i=0; I <= arr.length; i++)
```

Comment: That isn't the problem, they said they could `console.log` the data they wanted. (It might be *a* problem, but certainly isn't the one being asked about.). Your code is also wrong. You can't change the case of a variable name.

Comment: Explain *why* using `<=` should be used. Also, explain why you're using a different variable (`I`) in the loop...