# How can I replace an element and the element in it with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace an element and the text in the element inside it with js code. But when I try this I get an error. This is because element 2 is inside element 1. But I need to use it this way and I couldn't find a solution. If you look at the sample code below, you will understand what I mean. Thank you from now.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="element_1">Test Div
 <p id="element_2">Test Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
document.getElementById("element_1").innerHTML = "New Div Text";
document.getElementById("element_2").innerHTML = "New Paragraph Text";
```

Result HTML:

```
<div id="element_1">New Div Text
  <p id="element_2">{empty}</p>
</div>
```

Error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Comment: When you do this `document.getElementById("element_1").innerHTML = "New Div Text";` your setting the innerHTML to just that plain text and destroying the nested `<p>` content. Therefore it is indeed not on the DOM and null.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change an element's text without changing its child elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements)

Comment: @Juan - Good find! I should have realized this was well-covered... :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Here is the question and solution. I found it because of you. I just didn't know how to ask. I tried and it works. Thanks again. Cheers!